# How to get SoC manufacturer and model natively?

Tags: java, android, operating-system, cpu

I want to get the SoC (System on Chip) Manufacturer and model, according to the documentation, this should be possible.

[image]

If I try return `Build.SOC_MODEL` - it fails by saying it cannot find that property.
I have a feeling it has something to with the fact those 2 fields are highlighted in yellow in the docs, what does that mean?

I just need a function that will return those 2 fields.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#SOC_MODEL

**EDIT**
Added in Android S (12). And my project is below that version. Sorted.